# wordpress: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My website is setup on a linux server and behind WAF. The files are placed in root folder of apache server. The .htaccess contains rules as specified by wordpress.

The issue is that when I try to access my website as https://www.example.com, it gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. But when I try to access the website as https://www.example.com/index.php, it loads and works perfectly fine.

The couple of things I tried to pinpoint the error:

- Deleted all files and folders from root folder and created a test index.php file. When I tried to access https://www.example.com, it displayed the contents of this test file
- I also tried deleting .htaccess but this didnt help

I am still unable to figure out what the issue is. Can anyone please help out?

Comment: Are you using any kind of load balancer to handle https, or can you tell me how your domain pointing to https ? is it certificate in your server or pointing from somewhere else such as load balancer ?

Comment: There might be couple reasons for that. So first of all you have to figure out why is that happening? I would check `error_log` file. Maybe it can show you what is the problem. On the other hand, you have to check your `functions.php` file. Try to compare your `functions.php` file with Wordpress' default `functions.php` file. You can use file difference checker for that.
If you share your `error_log` file, maybe I can help you more.

Comment: I have applied certificate and also mod_ssl is installed

Comment: @rawsly let me see if I can share the error_log

Comment: @rawsly  nothing significant in error_log.

Comment: Okay, try to deactivate your plugins one by one and check if anything changes.

Comment: Already tried that, no change!

Comment: Okay so we eliminated couple factors. If you are able to connect your `wp-admin` page, try to use different theme. If this doesnt work, the problem is probably in your `wp-includes` folder. Backup that folder and change it with default wordpress `wp-includes` folder. See if anything changes. If that does not work too, try to change your root wordpress files (`wp-activate`, `wp-settings` `wp-signup` and etc.) with the original files.

Comment: @rawsly I did as you suggested but did not work. I did add some code in functions.php to check whether https://www.example.com displays that code and well it does. Any more suggestions?

Comment: maybe it is about your database. have you checked your `wp_options` tabla? to make sure it is about your database, you can install a fresh wordpress and check if you can access your fresh wordpress installation.

Comment: @rawsly i dont think it is database issue since https://www.example.com/index.php is working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a LOT of suggested solutions online, I fixed the issue by using the plugin Redirection.  This plugin solved my issue within minutes!!

Here is the [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/) to the article which helped me.

Answer (score 0):

disable all your plugins. 
in your theme if you using redirect code in your functions or other page , use exit() or die() after your redirect code.